# Ansible: Use array to create a variable

Tags: arrays, ansible

To deploy the ldap.conf with Ansible, I have to create one variable from an array, to use in a template ldap.conf.j2:

```
nss_base_group          {{ ldap_base_group }}
```

The variable array:

```
---
ldap_groups: [ 'ORACLE', 'MY_SQL', 'POSTGR' ]
```

This has to result in one parameter, enhanced with al lot of static characters:

```
ldap_base_group:"dc=foo,dc=com?sub?(&(|(memberof:1.2.654.123456.1.5.2468:=cn=ORACLE,ou=Groups,dc=foo,dc=com)(memberof:1.2.654.123456.1.5.2468:=cn=MY_SQL,ou=Groups,dc=foo,dc=com)(memberof:1.2.654.123456.1.5.2468:=cn=POSTGR,ou=Groups,dc=foo,dc=com))(!(userAccountControl:1.2.654.123456.1.5.654:=2)))"
```

This is the same parameter made readable (not usable because of newlines, spaces etc):

```
ldap_base_group: "dc=foo,dc=com?sub?
(&
    (|
            (memberof:1.2.654.123456.1.5.2468:=cn=ORACLE,ou=Groups,dc=foo,dc=com)
            (memberof:1.2.654.123456.1.5.2468:=cn=MY_SQL,ou=Groups,dc=foo,dc=com)
            (memberof:1.2.654.123456.1.5.2468:=cn=POSTGR,ou=Groups,dc=foo,dc=com)
    )
    (!
            (userAccountControl:1.2.654.123456.1.5.654:=2)
    )
)"
```

Does anyone has found a nice solution to do this in Ansible? Maybe there is an other way to do this, I am eager to know alternatives too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you template this you should be able to do something along these lines:

```
ldap_base_group: "dc=foo,dc=com?sub?
(&
    (|
    {% for group in ldap_groups %}
            (memberof:1.2.654.123456.1.5.2468:=cn={{ group }},ou=Groups,dc=foo,dc=com)
    {% endfor %}
    )
    (!
            (userAccountControl:1.2.654.123456.1.5.654:=2)
    )
)"
```

If you need everything in a single line then just flattening this out should work fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've put it in the vars-dir and removed the newlines and the spaces outside the {{ }}. It works perfect!